# Angular 12. Circular dependency for ApplicationRef

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, circular-dependency

I'm getting `Error: NG0200: Circular dependency in DI detected for ApplicationRef.` in case:

```
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { MyModalComponent } from 'MyModalComponentPath';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyCoreService {
    constructor(
        private modalController: ModalController
    ) { }
    
    private async openModal(): Promise<void> {
        const modal = await this.modalController.create({
            component: MyModalComponent
        });

        modal.present();
    }
}
```

Also I have similar core services using ModalController without this error.

How is the circular dependency possible here? Did anyone faced this issue?

Full error message:

```
Error: NG0200: Circular dependency in DI detected for ApplicationRef. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0200
    at throwCyclicDependencyError (core.js:216)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.js:11433)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:11256)
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.js:4751)
    at Module.ɵɵinject (core.js:4755)
    at Object.AngularDelegate_Factory [as factory] (ionic-angular.js:2320)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.js:11437)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:11256)
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.js:4751)
    at Module.ɵɵinject (core.js:4755)
```

Comment: it would be nice to post the full error text. it should contain the circle.

Comment: I found hack solution for similar scenario (sourse: https://github.com/ngneat/hot-toast/issues/70), but still it does not explain the true cause of the error

Comment: Hi Ihor, can you show us your app.module.ts for detect the problem. I think you doesnt include hot-toast right way.

Answer (score 2):

I get the exact same error as you. After doing a bit of testing i've found out that the error only occurs when you inject `ModalController` into the `constructor` of a `Service` that is used by the currently active `Component`.

I have no idea what is causing this but a workaround is to lazy load the `ModalController` into the `Service` using an `Injector` instance. That will stop a cyclic dependency error from getting thrown.

Below is some code to illustrate this:

```
    import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
    import { Injector } from '@angular/core';
    
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class MyService {
    
      constructor(private injector:Injector){}

      async presentModalDialog(params: any) {
        const modal = await this.injector.get(ModalController).create({  //The lazy loading is done with the get method of Injector
          component: ModalDialogComponent,
          componentProps: params,
        });
        return await modal.present();
      }
    
    }
```

Alternatively you could also use the `Injector` instance to load the `ModalController` only once and then assign the instance to a class variable of type `ModalController`.

Comment: Thank you for effort! I found something similar on https://github.com/ngneat/hot-toast/issues/70, but this is a workaround and not a real solution

Comment: @Ihor the error is probably caused by a bug in ionic itself. Also because this error only occurs when injecting the controller into the constructor of a service.